# Get value of TensorFlow JS model.predict into a variable

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to implement a neural network in JS, which can predict certain values and then store these values in a variable for later use.

```
async function processModel(inputs) {
  const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(modelURL);
  inputs = tf.tensor(inputs);

  var predictions = model.predict(inputs);
  predictions = predictions.dataSync();

  console.log(typeof(predictions));

  return predictions;
}
```

Launching this informs me that `predictions` is of type `object`.
I would like to get the values of the Promise which is returned and store these values in a variable, so I can compare them to other variables.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 3):

You can access the predicted values in the output Tensor using the arraySync() method. For e.g. if the output Tensor is a two dimensional array with only a single output value, then the code below will give you the predicted value.

```
 const resultTensor = model.predict(tf.tensor2d([50], [1, 1]));
 const predictedValue = resultTensor.arraySync()[0][0];
 console.log(predictedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

`prredictions` in an array. The array indexing is the way to get the predicted value

Answer (score 0):

According to [datasync method](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.dataSync), `variable.dataSync()` returns `DataTypeMap[NumericDataType]`. It returns a `TypedArray` of any `NumericDataType`.

According to [MDN documentation on TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray),

> a `TypedArray` object describes an array-like view of an underlying
>   binary data buffer.

So, you are correct that `console.log(typeof(predictions))` will print `object` in the console.

But as `predictions` is a `TypedArray`, you can use it like regular JavaScript array. You can print `predictions[0]` and so on.

Let's see an example of `TypedArray`:

```js
// create a TypedArray with a size in bytes
const typedArrayExample = new Float32Array(2);
typedArrayExample[0] = 32.36;

console.log(typeof(typedArrayExample));   // object
console.log(typedArrayExample);           // {"0": 32.36000061035156, "1": 0}
console.log(typedArrayExample[0]);        // 32.36000061035156
```

#### Reference:

- [Documentation on datasync method](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.dataSync)
- [MDN documentation on TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray)
- [Documentation on predict method](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.GraphModel.predict)